# Function Declaration объявленная в цикле JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,помогите разобраться почему Function Declaration объявленная в цикле,создается на каждой итерации.

Из https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression

> Основное отличие между ними: функции, объявленные как Function
>   Declaration, создаются интерпретатором до выполнения кода.

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  function example() {}
  example.i = i;
  arr.push(example);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Вопрос возник когда разбирался с NFE которые создаются в процессе выполнения выражения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле в конкретном примере нет абсолютно никакой разницы, используется ли функциональное объявление или функциональное выражение:

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  function example() {}
  example.i = i;
  arr.push(example);
}

console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]); // === arr[2] === ... => false
```

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var f = function example() {};
  f.i = i;
  arr.push(f);
}

console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]); // === arr[2] === ... => false
```

В обоих случаях идентификатор будет перезаписываться. В первом случае, с Function Declaration, вы просто на каждой итерации цикла заново объявляете функцию `example`. Во втором же случае вы каждый раз заново определяете (переопределяете) переменную `f`. И в обоих случаях в массив записывается та функция, которая только что была объявлена.

Именно поэтому каждый раз это разная функция, а не ссылка на одну и ту же функцию (как вы можете видеть из моих примеров - ни одна функция не равно другой).

> Здравствуйте,помогите разобраться почему Function Declaration объявленная в цикле,создается на каждой итерации.

Встречный вопрос: а какого поведения вы могли ожидать?

Воспроизведите этот код:

```js
function example() {
  return 1;
}

function example() {
  return 2;
}

function example() {
  return 3;
}

function example() {
  return 4;
}

function example() {
  return 5;
}

console.log(example());
```

В этом примере я реализовал то, что мог бы реализовать циклом, но сделал это вручную. Значение `example` равняется последней объявленной функции с этим именем. Проще говоря, `example` просто *перезаписывается*.

Абсолютно то же самое происходит и внутри цикла. На первой итерации вы определили функцию и добавили ее в массив. На второй итерации вы *переопределили* ранее определенную функцию и добавили *уже переопределенную* функцию в массив. И так далее.

---

Что касается этой части:

> Основное отличие между ними: функции, объявленные как Function Declaration, создаются интерпретатором до выполнения кода.

Тут, вероятно, речь идет про, так называемый, Variable Hoisting. Про него уже достаточно много сказано, но, чтобы ответ соответствовал ответу, приведу цитату из книги С. Стоянова, которая максимально точно отражает происходящее "под капотом" (перевод под оригиналом):

> To avoid hoisting always use a function expression.

```js
// antipattern
// for illustration only
// global functions
function foo() {
  alert('global foo');
}

function bar() {
  alert('global bar');
}

function hoistMe() {
  console.log(typeof foo); // "function"
  console.log(typeof bar); // "undefined"
  foo(); // "local foo"
  bar(); // TypeError: bar is not a function
  // function declaration:
  // variable 'foo' and its implementation both get hoisted

  function foo() {
    alert('local foo');
  }
  // function expression:
  // only variable 'bar' gets hoisted
  // not the implementation
  var bar = function() {
    alert('local bar');
  };
}
hoistMe();
```

> In this example you see that, just like with normal variables, the mere presence of foo
>   and bar anywhere in the hoistMe() function moves them to the top, overwriting the
>   global foo and bar.

---

### Перевод

> Чтобы избежать хоистинга, всегда используйте функциональные выражения (Function Expressions)

```js
// антипаттерн
// только для примера
// глобальные функции
function foo() {
  alert('global foo');
}

function bar() {
  alert('global bar');
}

function hoistMe() {
  console.log(typeof foo); // "function"
  console.log(typeof bar); // "undefined"
  foo(); // "local foo"
  bar(); // TypeError: bar is not a function
  // function declaration:
  // переменная 'foo' и ее реализация "хоистятся"

  function foo() {
    alert('local foo');
  }
  // function expression:
  // только переменная 'bar' "хоистится",
  // не ее реализация
  var bar = function() {
    alert('local bar');
  };
}
hoistMe();
```

> В этом примере вы можете видеть, что, также, как и с "обычными" переменными, только лишь наличие `foo` или `bar` где угодно внутри функции `hoistMe()` перемещает их вверх функции, перезаписывая [ранее определенные] глобальные `foo` и `bar`.

Comment: Я ожидал сообщения,что функция уже определена.Сразу открыл консоль и набрал var a = 5;var a;var a; и надо же сообщения об ошибке нет...

Comment: @Александр как видите - нет. Приоритет у той функции, которая определена позже других (разумеется, речь про одинаково названные функции).

Comment: Отличное объяснение!!!Теперь я понимаю,что в цикле просто перезаписывается свойство глобального объекта window.example.

Comment: По области видимости тоже,помог разобраться еще пример var a = 1; 
function b() { 
    a = 10; 
    return; 
    function a() {} 
} 
b(); 
alert(a);

Comment: @Александр про перезапись window.example в данном конкретном случае - да, абсолютно верно. А вот про область видимости я вроде ничего особо не расписывал... Но все равно на здоровье :)

Comment: [block level function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics)

Comment: @Grundy ого Вы отрыли (я про вопрос-ответ)

Comment: @smellyshovel, Это я просто искал дубликат для другого вопроса и случайно попкал

Comment: @Grundy я только, если честно, не совсем понял, к чему ссылка. Вроде написанное в спецификации не делает мой ответ неправильным, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @smellyshovel, это скорее объяснение _почему_ это так работает. Ну и хоистинг тут _своеобразный_

Comment: @Grundy а, ну хорошо. Не очень-то хотелось переписывать уже так давно написанное. В любом случае, спасибо за инфу.

Answer (score 0):

Походу, если функция объявляется в цикле, то она **не создается** интерпретатором до выполнения кода. Зато, так как функция в js - это переменная, то ей можно добавлять поле с ключом i, переопределять его в цикле и переопределять всю функцию. После выполнения цикла в ней будут хранится последние значения

```js
var arr = [];

try {
    example();
} catch (err) {
    console.log("error: "+err)
}

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    function example(){console.log("func init #"+i)}
    example.i = i;
    arr.push(example);
}

console.log(example.i);
example();
```

Comment: У функции может быть свойство `i` не потому, что она переменная, а потому, что функция - это объект.

Comment: там самое прикольное, что не смотря на то, что в глобальном скоупе по имени exaple хранится только последнее определение функции в цикле, но в массиве arr, хранятся какого-то хрена предыдущие состояния example

Comment: Так все логично. При пуше в массив не ссылка на последнее состояние записывается, а сам объект функции. Точнее, это как бы все равно ссылка на функцию, но именно на ту копию этой функции, в состоянии которой она была в момент пуша. Я думаю. жить было бы намного сложнее, будь логика работы такая, как ожидали вы.

Comment: И вообще нет, я вам соврал. Это именно что ни на есть отдельные копии функции.

Comment: А я думаю так можно легко устроить лик и выстрелить себе в ногу расплодив объекты. В цикле не стоит ничего определять)

Comment: Тоже верно. Если честно, слабо даже могу себе представить ситуацию, в которой это может быть необходимо.

Comment: Кстати, ваш пример меня немного насторожил. Всегда был уверен что область Variable Hoisting'а определяется границами функции, но никак не блока. Видимо, ошибался, надо бы перечитать спецификацию.

Comment: не нашел такого в спецификации, тоже думал как и вы. Может плохо читали.